# Listing files with Process.run

Tags: dart

I'm tring to execute this command Process.run `ls /dev/tty.*`
On my Mac, its return : `/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem`
but when I executing by Process.run

```dart
Process.run('ls', ['/dev/tty.*']).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
});
```

It print nothing.
After some tests, it appears using asterisk is the cause of my problem. Indeed, when I just list files from /dev

```dart
Process.run('ls', ['/dev/']).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
});
```

It prints all files and directory.
Is there special thing to do when list files with asterik ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard is interpreded by the shell.

try

```dart
Process.run('/bin/sh', ['-c', 'ls /dev/tty.*']).then((ProcessResult results) {
  print(results.stdout);
});
```